# How to remove preventDefault behaviour of Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) dropdown menu in my markup. But other than the default behaviour, it should pop out if I'm hovering the elements. So I created a small script:

```
jQ('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    jQ(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    jQ(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeOut();
});
```

which is working fine. But for some reason the Bootstrap dropdown prevents redirecting to another page when I want to have the first item (which triggers the hover) as a link. I'm clicking on the link and nothing happens, it only appends a class `.open`. I only can open the link if I do a right click and select `open destination in new tab`. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Implement the `onclick` of the `a` as: `document.location.href=this.href`. Does that work?

Comment: What's with the cute `jQ`? :)

Comment: You can bind any element to a redirection click : `$(".whatever").click( function(){ window.location='some/url'; })`

Comment: @JeremyThille haha, its for noConflict(), any new suggestions? ;)

Comment: @Halcyon I don't want necessarily use jQuery, just want to know what causes this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remove `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute from the button (I suppose it's anchor tag):

```
<a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" href="http://somewhere" target="_blank" id="dropdownMenu1" >
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7vaxf4g/)

---

`data-toggle` attribute is an indicator for bootstrap, that an event should be bind to the element, depends on the attribute value:

```
data-toggle="dropdown"
data-toggle="tooltip"
data-toggle="modal"
data-toggle="popover"
data-toggle="tab"
data-toggle="collapse"
data-toggle="button"
```

**NOTE**:
You may have a problem on mobile devices with the "click open link" scenario.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I removed the data-toggle and it still does not work.

Comment: @supersize , This works in standard scenario, with anchor tag as button and without any script that would affect `click` event (see JSFiddle). I thought that your case is the standard scenario, because you didn't post any HTML/js code for that